# How to retrieve date without time in the yyyymmdd format in C#

Tags: c#, date

Can somebody kindly help in addressing this issue:

```
string datetime = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyymmdd")
```

I would like to have date in the yyyymmdd format without any separator in between.

Please stop downvoting this question. I got the message loud and clear that this question lacks research effort and also doesn't add an iota of usefulness to the SO programming.

Comment: Use `MM` for the month, `mm` are minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
string todayDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
string todayDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Except from:

```
string todayDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

You could also use:

```
string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

In your case it is actually doing the same thing. If you want so get it more specific I think `.Now` is better.

For all of the different possibilities take a look at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

The correct DateTime format string would be `yyyyMMdd`.

Answer (score 0):

The month part of your string should be MM (month from 01 to 12) instead of mm:

```
string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings